# Send form data via GET to page already with variables

Tags: php, https, webforms, http-get

This code is only passing the form's GET data, not the GET data that I've already put in there. Why is this?

```
  <form action="functions.php?q=log" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="url" />
  <input type="submit" />
  </form>
```

Comment: Did you ever work this out? Would you mind letting us know or accept an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I would create a hidden input like this:

`<input type="hidden name="q" value="log" />` and then use `action="functions.php"`.

Like this:

```
<form action="functions.php" method="GET">
  <input type="text" name="url" />
  <input type="hidden" name="q" value="log" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you append get data to a form:

```
<form action="functions.php" method="GET">
<input type="hidden" name="q" value="log" />
<input type="text" name="url" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

About all I can see is that it could be that the data in the form is overwriting the url and not appending to it.